# How do I ask a question about someone's order of birth?

Tags: questions, numbers, ordinal-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Framing a question whose answer is an ordinal number](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11481/framing-a-question-whose-answer-is-an-ordinal-number)
>   [How to phrase an asking sentence that must be answered with an ordinal number?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13662/how-to-phrase-an-asking-sentence-that-must-be-answered-with-an-ordinal-number-e)
>   [How to ask a question to get a cardinal number answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21876/how-to-ask-a-question-to-get-a-cardinal-number-answer)

My friend is the second child of her mother.
How would I ask her that apart from asking - Are you the second daughter? - like I need to ask the order of her birth. How will I ask it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have just asked about other siblings, you could continue with something like this:

> Where do you fall in the line?

It is also common to just guess one scenario and ask if is is correct:

> Are you the oldest?

Or if you have just been told about the sister, ask specifically about the relative relation:

> Is your sister younger or older than you?

Comment: What if I have not asked about other siblings?? And all the other answers are not what I asked for.. those things we could manage. Is there an direct sentence that i can use to know what i am seeking?

Comment: My answer attempt was just about cultural English, RegDwight spotted you were trying to ask a very common question about asking questions where the answer is an ordinal number. The other questions should help you find something useful.