# Interrogative form of a sentence

Tags: numbers, ordinal-numbers, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I phrase a question that must be answered with an ordinal number (e.g., the third prime)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13662/how-should-i-phrase-a-question-that-must-be-answered-with-an-ordinal-number-e-g)
>   [How to ask a question to get a cardinal number answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21876/how-to-ask-a-question-to-get-a-cardinal-number-answer)

> Neil Armstrong was the first man on the Moon.

I need to convert this into a question.
If "Neil Armstrong" was the answer, the interrogative form would be

> Who was the first man on the Moon?

How do you ask this as a question if "first" was the answer?

Another example would be

> Abraham Lincoln was the 16th President of the United States

Comment: You cannot form such a interrogative sentence. That is a very tricky question and i don't think there exists a word in English vocabulary which would convey this meaning. Try using the word "Rank" though it doesn't serve the whole purpose but that is the nearest i could think of.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no provision for such form of interrogative sentence in English. The closest form of asking would be

*whence did Neil Armstrong land on the moon?*

However, this question could not necessarily be answered "first".

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for the English translation of a [Telugu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telugu_language) sentence. But, it looks like there isn't one.