# What is the question for which the answer is "This is my third coffee today"?

Tags: numbers, ordinal-numbers, questions

> **Duplicate of:**
>   [How should I phrase a question that must be answered with an ordinal number (e.g., the third prime)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13662/how-should-i-phrase-a-question-that-must-be-answered-with-an-ordinal-number-e-g)
>   [Framing a question to which the answer is an ordinal number](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11481/framing-a-question-to-which-the-answer-is-an-ordinal-number)
>   [How manyth son to your father?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73847/how-manyth-son-to-your-father)
>   [How will I ask this particular question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30879/how-will-i-ask-this-particular-question)
>   [How to ask a question to get an ordinal number answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21876/how-to-ask-a-question-to-get-an-ordinal-number-answer)
>   [How can I ask a question with the answer “I'm eating the fourth apple”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66659/how-can-i-ask-a-question-with-the-answer-im-eating-the-fourth-apple)
>   [How do you say this in English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24673/how-do-you-say-this-in-english) 
>   [How to ask “nth time” of something](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47107/how-to-ask-nth-time-of-something)
>   [Interrogative form of a sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57545/interrogative-form-of-a-sentence)
>   [What will be the question for “he is my second son”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/86869/what-will-be-the-question-for-he-is-my-second-son)
>   [How do you convert the sentence “George Washington was the first president.” to a question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77222/how-do-you-convert-the-sentence-george-washington-was-the-first-president-to)
>   [How to frame a question to get answer about the turn that somebody has taken in doing something?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68412/how-to-frame-a-question-to-get-answer-about-the-turn-that-somebody-has-taken-in)
>   [Asking question about position of a person in a list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65884/asking-question-about-position-of-a-person-in-a-list)
>   [How do I ask this as a question in English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62044/how-do-i-ask-this-as-a-question-in-english)
>   [A question for this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91651/a-question-for-this-answer)

I would like to know: How to ask a question such that the expected answer includes the "*n<sup>th</sup>* thing"?

The only way I could do of to do this is by asking:

> How many cups of coffee have you had today?

but the answer to that would be, *"3"*, not *"This is my third..."*

Comment: Could you at least elaborate, and explain why _"How many cups of coffee have you had today?"_ (to which one might reply, _"Three."_) would be undesirable?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This question has been asked (and answered) here before: [How should I phrase a question that must be answered with an ordinal number (e.g., the third prime)?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13662/how-should-i-phrase-a-question-that-must-be-answered-with-an-ordinal-number-e-g)

Comment: @StoneyB: that may answer the question, yes, but you gotta admit, it sure makes for an awkward way to ask about the morning joe.

Comment: Please search the site before posting. This question gets asked so often, it's even on the [FAQ tab](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=faq). Thank you.

Comment: @J.R.  To be sure; but if you want to be colloquial you don't  constrain answers to a specific form.

Comment: The OP is looking for someone to ask a question like "OF all the cups of coffee you will have to day, in order, which one is this?" a question whose need is not desired in any of the known universes. "How many cups of coffe have you had?" "This is my third." That suffices.

Comment: @Mitch That’s your which cup of coffee?