# Asking question about position of a person in a list

Tags: grammar, ordinal-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I phrase a question that must be answered with an ordinal number (e.g., the third prime)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13662/how-should-i-phrase-a-question-that-must-be-answered-with-an-ordinal-number-e-g)
>   [How to ask a question to get a cardinal number answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21876/how-to-ask-a-question-to-get-a-cardinal-number-answer)

In my Regional language 'Malayalam' there is a word 'എത്രാമത്തെ' (HOW MANY'TH) for asking question about position of a person in a list.

eg: Barack Obama is 'How many'th' American President ?

for the answer "Obama is  44th President of USA"

in english. Is there anything in English for this?