# How can I ask a question with the answer "I'm eating the fourth apple"?

Tags: questions, ordinal-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I phrase a question that must be answered with an ordinal number (e.g., the third prime)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13662/how-should-i-phrase-a-question-that-must-be-answered-with-an-ordinal-number-e-g)
>   [Framing a question to which the answer is an ordinal number](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11481/framing-a-question-to-which-the-answer-is-an-ordinal-number)
>   [How to ask a question to get a cardinal number answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21876/how-to-ask-a-question-to-get-a-cardinal-number-answer)

Assume that there are 5 apples must be eaten by Jack. When you want to know about how many of the apples are eaten, you may ask Jack, 'how many apples have you eaten?'; But how can I ask the question to make Jack answers, 'I'm eating the fourth apple'?

Answer (score 4):

The social and linguistic context would usually make clear what was meant if you asked Jack 'Which one are you on now?'