# How to frame a question to get answer about the turn that somebody has taken in doing something?

Tags: questions, ordinal-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I phrase a question that must be answered with an ordinal number (e.g., the third prime)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13662/how-should-i-phrase-a-question-that-must-be-answered-with-an-ordinal-number-e-g)
>   [How to ask a question to get a cardinal number answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21876/how-to-ask-a-question-to-get-a-cardinal-number-answer)

I want to frame a question for which the answer will be :

> Obama is the 46th president

I am not looking for "who is the 46th president?" I trying to ask a question where I want to quiz the other person on Obama's turn (46) as a president.

For instance(incorrectly)

> "Howmanyth" president is Obama ?

Comment: also [Framing a question to which the answer is an ordinal number](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/11481/19644)

Comment: Obama is the 44th President. Get your facts straight.