# Is ''How many stops is Tokyo from here?'' grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

When do you want to ask which stop you want to get off at, can I say *how many stops is Tokyo from here?*? In this situation, I expect an answer like '5 stops.'

Comment: You would probably get better information about Tokyo subway stops by asking this in Japanese.

Comment: Also: "How many more stops until Tokyo?"; or, "How many more stops until I/we reach Tokyo?"

Comment: Don't you know English became the official language in Tokyo?

Comment: Regardless of language, the most likely answer is probably going to be along the lines of, “Which station? Tokyo has about a hundred…”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes you are right, but I was talking with one of my friends about how we can pull out an answer like ''6th stop'' from a bus driver or someone else in English. But we realised we can't ask the exactly same question as in Japanese. To which question can you answer, for example, ''Mary is the 7th sister'' ? You might be able to say ''Mary has her 6 older sisters'' or ''6 sisters were born before Mary,'' however, there is supposed to be no equivalent of ~番目

Comment: @Tom That’s a slightly different question—the question you ask in the question here would _not_ be answered with an ordinal number. There are a few other questions on here that deal with this issue, though: [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13662/how-should-i-phrase-a-question-that-must-be-answered-with-an-ordinal-number-e-g) and [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102618/how-manieth-as-an-ordinal-number-question) especially.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet These are the exactly what I wanted to say. Thanks.+1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the question is perfectly valid English.

Another way to say the same thing would be:  "How many stops until Tokyo?"

Comment: Except that if you ask it in the US the likely response is "Buddy, you're on the wrong train."

Answer (score 0):

Also:

> Separation - Page 110 Ben Bell
>
> I can just enjoy it, and flow along with all the streams of people,
>   from train to train, escalator to escalator, marvelling at the
>   vastness of it all. **“How many stops to East Finchley?”** Approaching
>   Mornington Crescent, the first of our stops on the way ...

Answer (score -1):

I think you should re-order the sentence to:

**How many stops are there from here to Tokyo?**