# Could you frame a question for this answer?

Tags: questions, question-tags

I have a statement which I want to use as an answer. The statement runs as follows:

Barack Obama is the 44th president of the United States of America.

Here the emphasis lies on the number 44.

What would be the question for the above statement? Please help.

Comment: exact duplicate of [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21876/how-to-ask-a-question-to-get-an-ordinal-number-answer) , which, in turn, is a duplicate of [this duplicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11481/framing-a-question-whose-answer-is-an-ordinal-number) of [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13662/how-should-i-phrase-a-question-that-must-be-answered-with-an-ordinal-number-e-g)