# How to ask "nth time" of something

Tags: questions, ordinal-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Framing a question to which the answer is an ordinal number](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11481/framing-a-question-to-which-the-answer-is-an-ordinal-number)
>   [How should I phrase a question that must be answered with an ordinal number (e.g., the third prime)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13662/how-should-i-phrase-a-question-that-must-be-answered-with-an-ordinal-number-e-g)

If the answer is

> This is my 6th bid

what will the question be?

Comment: How many bids is this, now?

Comment: Say you had to place 20 bids on ebay.
Only every bid there's a bid price and nth number of bid you placed on that auction.
That's what I'm looking for.