# How to ask this as question

Tags: grammar, word-usage, tenses

I am wondering how to turn the following into a question

> "Narendra Modi is the 18th Prime Minister of India"

How to ask this as question, so that answer will be  **18th**

I have tried searching these links but couldn't match my needs.

[How to ask "nth time" of something](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47107/how-to-ask-nth-time-of-something)

[Framing a question whose answer is an ordinal number](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11481/framing-a-question-whose-answer-is-an-ordinal-number)

[How should I phrase a question that must be answered with an ordinal number (e.g., the third prime)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13662/how-should-i-phrase-a-question-that-must-be-answered-with-an-ordinal-number-e-g)

Some body could help me.. Sorry If I'm vague and dont lambast at me since this is my first post here.

Comment: I trawled through the responses to the duplicate question, and also the responses to the duplicate of the duplicate question, and didn't find a single suggestion there that would more or less guarantee an answer in your desired format. However, try this: "Thinking of how many premierships India has had so far, please tell me which number is Prime Minister Modi's?"

Comment: @ErikKowal your are too kind. The answers said already doesn't meet my expectations. Thank you very much for answer and I really love the way you placed the words.

Comment: I was glad to be able to help. :-)

Comment: In the line of succession, what number is Narendra Modi as Prime Minister of India? Perhaps this might work.