# What will be the question for "he is my second son"

Tags: questions, ordinal-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I phrase a question that must be answered with an ordinal number (e.g., the third prime)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13662/how-should-i-phrase-a-question-that-must-be-answered-with-an-ordinal-number-e-g)
>   [How do you convert the sentence “George Washington was the first president.” to a question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77222/how-do-you-convert-the-sentence-george-washington-was-the-first-president-to)
>   [How manyth son to your father?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73847/how-manyth-son-to-your-father)

What will be the correct question to get an answer like "he is my *second* son". Here the actual answer is the word '*second*', which denotes the order.

Can the phrase '*ordinal status*' be used? Like "What is the *ordinal status* of Mr. Singh among the prime ministers of India"? Is this correct?

Comment: Your solution is not wrong, but I suggest it will be incomprehensible unless the answer is demanded of a mathematician.

Answer (score 2):

How about "Where does your son fall in terms of your children's birth order?"

Comment: That's a good one!