# How do you convert the sentence "George Washington was the first president." to a question?

Tags: questions, ordinal-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I phrase a question that must be answered with an ordinal number (e.g., the third prime)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13662/how-should-i-phrase-a-question-that-must-be-answered-with-an-ordinal-number-e-g)

How do you convert the sentence:

> George Washington was the first president.

into a question, preferably one in the form:

> ****Missing Phrase**** president is George Washington?

---

If no equivalent sentence that is not awkward sounding exists, ***why*** is there no English equivalent for the word *how-many-th*?

Comment: _Is_ or _was_ ?

Comment: Yes, I saw that question. However, I provided a specific format. This was not answered in that post. Thanks for pointing it out anyway.

Comment: @James The answer is that there is no common and grammatical equivalent in English. "How many'th" or "which positioned" do not really work. It's best to simply structure the question differently.

Comment: Wow. I can't believe the English Language doesn't have a word for that.

Comment: Damn language! I say we trade it in for German.

Answer (score 2):

*What was George Washington's place in the sequence [order?] of U.S. presidents.*

Comment: He was number one.

Answer (score -1):

The obvious answer to a question phrased like that,

> [*MissingPhrase*] president was George Washington?

is "What number president was George Washington?"

A: George Washington was the first president. George Washington was president number one.