# Shortest question to ask when you want to know whether the one you talk to is the eldest, second, third...or youngest child in his/her family.

Tags: questions, translation

I’ve always been asked by my Filipino friends how I should say the Filipino question “Pang-ilan ka sa magkakapatid?” in English.

You ask that question when you want to know whether someone is the eldest, second, third...or youngest child in the family. What’s the shortest way to ask such question without necessarily mentioning choices (eldest, second, etc.) as the Filipino question also does not mention the choices?

Comment: There isn't any conventional way of asking this. I can only think of "Where do you come in the family?" or "Are your siblings older or younger than you?"

Comment: You can simply ask '*are you the eldest son/daughter/child of your parents/ in your family?*'. Then they will answer you with the exact ordinal position such as *I'm the eldest, second, youngest etc.*

Comment: Welcome to the site. This or a similar question has been asked several times here. One example: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131683/how-to-ask-about-ordinal-place-of-an-offspring

Comment: How many older siblings do you have?

Comment: @KateBunting I like "Where do you come in the family?" but it could be answered in terms of perceived status rather than age. For instance I once knew a man who had a wife,  a daughter and a dog and it was generally agreed among those who knew him that he came after the dog in his family!

Answer (score -1):

You could ask

> Where are you in the birth order?