# How to ask what is your number in the siblings or to your parents.?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

How to ask what is your number in the siblings or to your parents

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Framing a question whose answer is an ordinal number](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11481/framing-a-question-whose-answer-is-an-ordinal-number) Also [How should I phrase a question that must be answered with an ordinal number (e.g., the third prime)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13662/how-should-i-phrase-a-question-that-must-be-answered-with-an-ordinal-number-e-g)

Comment: Do want the information or are you trying to get them to answer in a very specific way?   “How many older siblings do you have?” gets you the information.

Answer (score 1):

You could ask two questions:

How many siblings do you have? and

Where are you in the birth order?

Comment: I'd add that the follow-up question depends on the answer to the first question: if they say "none" then of course you wouldn't ask about birth order, and if they say "one" then you could ask "are you (the) youngest or oldest?"