# Framing a question to which you reply with "I am the third born in my family"

Tags: questions, numbers, kinship-terms, ordinal-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Framing a question to which the answer is an ordinal number](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11481/framing-a-question-to-which-the-answer-is-an-ordinal-number)

would it be if i asked what is your relative position terms of birth order in your family

Comment: I can't quite tell what you're trying to ask. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

If you asked me "what is your relative position in terms of birth order in your family", I would answer "I am the second born in my family".  (In my particular case, I could also say "I am the youngest of my siblings".)  So, if I understand your question correctly, yes, "what is your relative..." would evoke the answer "I am the second...".

Answer (score 1):

There are a handful of questions that could prompt such an answer:

> Are you an oldest child?
>
> No, I am the third born in my family.

---

> How many older siblings do you have?
>
> I am the third born in my family.

---

> List you and your siblings in order.
>
> John is the first born; Jack is the second. I am the third born in my family.

Of note, the tail "in my family" is mostly redundant. More succinct responses are "I am the third born" or "I am third." In any case, the response seems to require a somewhat awkward question. The odds of this answer being used in everyday conversation is pretty slim.