# How to ask this as a question in grammatically correct way

Tags: grammar, questions

What is the correct way to ask a question to get the following answer. Question should ask what is the number (7) of Maithripala Sirisena

> Maithripala Sirisena is 7th Executive President of Sri Lanka

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Framing a question whose answer is an ordinal number](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11481/framing-a-question-whose-answer-is-an-ordinal-number)

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

"Which Executive President of Sri Lanka was/is Maithripala Sirisena?" (was/is depending on whether he is the incumbent or a past official)

This usually implies the answer should be a number.

You might also ask:

"Who was/is the seventh Executive President of Sri Lanka?"